# Listen to specifique key pressing

Tags: key-bindings

I'd like to call a (vimscript-) function, if I'm pressing the return key. Is it possible to do that in vim? Because currently this doesn't work:

```
function Test()
    echom "test"
endfunction

inoremap <CR> call Test()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create an Insert-mode mapping (`inoremap`), the expansion is interpreted as keystrokes in Insert-mode, so your example will actually just enter the `call Test()` text as a literal.

In order to call a function from that mapping, you need to first exit Insert mode, then use `:` to enter the `:call` command and finally use a `<CR>` to execute it.

You can also use the `<C-O>` command, which allows you to execute a single Normal-mode command and return to Insert-mode when done.

This will work to call the function when you press `<CR>` in Insert-mode:

```
inoremap <CR> <C-O>:call Test()<CR>
```

Comment: Nice! I can call my function but the cursor behaves "strange" but do you have an idea, how I can keep the insert-mode-cursor-behaviour? Like the indentation adjusting if I open write a curly bracket and type enter that my cursor gets the bigger indentation and the ending curly bracket goes to the next line.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean... If it's related to the position of the cursor (particularly if you're at the end of the line), you could try `<C-\><C-O>` to see if it preserves it. Your question is asking how to call a function from a mapping (which is what I addressed in my answer.) You might want to post a separate question about what you want to accomplish more specifically, as not always calling a function this way is the best way to do it...

Comment: You're rigth. I'll mark your answer as accepted and I'll create a new questin for that. Thank you again sir for your answer :)